# Roslyn Only Compiler Error with Lambda Statements: Expression cannot be converted into an expression tree

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.5, moq, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

**Question**

How can I rewrite the below Moq tests so they work again in Roslyn? Obviously I could remove the Lambda, but I was hoping to avoid that.

Also, for interest sake: did the Roslyn compiler fix a bug that allowed these invalid statements to work previously or is this a compiler bug that now breaks these statements?

**Details**

I'm trying to move my mostly VB.NET solution to Visual Studio 2015, from Visual Studio 2013. All projects in the solution are targeting .NET 4.5. I am currently using Moq 4.0 for these tests. I have several Moq based Lambda unit tests that fail to compile in Visual Studio 2015, but compile and run fine in Visual Studio 2013. These tests have worked in Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 as well.

Most of the tests are very simple and look something like this:

```
Private _view As Mock(Of Views.ICreateSecurityUserView)

<Test>
Public Sub ValidateSave_CallWithBlankLogin_SetsViewToolError()
    _view = New Mock(Of Views.ICreateSecurityUserView)()

    _view.SetupGet(Of String)(Function(x) x.Login).Returns("")
    _view.SetupGet(Of String)(Function(x) x.LoginName).Returns(loginNameValue)

    _subject.ValidateSave()
    _view.Verify(Sub(x) x.LoginFieldError = It.Is(Of String)(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)), Times.Once)
End Sub
```

The offending line will be this one: `_view.Verify(Sub(x) x.LoginFieldError = It.Is(Of String)(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)), Times.Once)`

The build error I get (as in the title) is:

> Error BC36534 Expression cannot be converted into an expression tree.

I've fiddled with the expression a bit, seeing if the compiler would be happier if it was multi-line:

```
_view.Verify(Sub(x)
                 x.LoginFieldError = It.Is(Of String)(Function(s)
                                                          Return Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)
                                                      End Function)
             End Sub, Times.Once)
```

But to no avail, since this just adds these extra errors (the Visual Studio 2013 compiler also doesn't like the multi-line version):

> Error BC36675 Statement lambdas cannot be converted to expression trees.

**Bad "Solution"**

I am able to get this compiling if I change the test line to:

```
_view.Verify(Sub(x) VerifyFunctionNameError(x), Times.Once)
```

Which then calls the new, pointless, function:

```
    Private Sub VerifyFunctionNameError(x As Views.ICreateSecurityFunctionView)
        x.FunctionNameError = It.Is(Of String)(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    End Sub
```

Comment: This used to be an answer, but I deleted it since it does not answer the question (solve the problem): _Moq has a method called `Is`, but in VB.NET `Is` is a reserved keyword. Therefore I think you must use `[Is]`, with brackets. However, that would be the same in Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012._

Comment: I've reported this as a bug at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4524 . If you could please post a complete narrowed-down test case on that thread we'd appreciate it. We'll fix it if we can.

Comment: Thanks Neal, I have added a comment with some code. I would be surprised now if it is something that needs to be fixed, but it's worth looking into.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My above "Bad Solution" in my question, doesn't actually even work anyway. This fails when the test runs because it obviously can't determine anything from the sub.

The actual answer to my question is to use `Mock.VerifySet`, instead of `Mock.Verify`. We are actually doing this in most places, so I'm not sure why we used the other method here. A rewritten test that will work in 2013 *and* 2015 will look like this:

```
_view.VerifySet(Sub(x) x.LoginFieldError = It.Is(Of String)(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)), Times.Once)
```

This compiles and the tests are passing as well.

I was poking around in the Moq source code today and the reason for the different result is seen below:

**Verify**

```
public void Verify(Expression<Action<T>> expression, Times times)
{
    Mock.Verify(this, expression, times, null);
}
```

**VerifySet**

```
public void VerifySet(Action<T> setterExpression, Times times)
{
    Mock.VerifySet(this, setterExpression, times, null);
}
```

The `Expression<Action<T>>` has apparently had its handling changed, while the `Action<T>` doesn't appear to have had its changed.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is hard to answer, I can't get a decent repro for this without knowing the declarations.  Nevertheless, there is certainly a hint why this should not compile from the VB.NET Language Specification.  Find a copy of it on your machine in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VB\Specifications\1033\Visual Basic Language Specification.docx

Navigate to chapter 11.1.1 and scroll down a bit to arrive at the Annotation block.  I'll quote the most relevant part:

> The exact translation between lambda methods and expression trees may not be fixed between versions of the compiler and is beyond the scope of this specification.  For Microsoft Visual Basic 11.0, all lambda expressions may be converted to expression trees subject to the following restrictions:
>   1.  Only single-line lambda expressions without ByRef parameters may be converted to expression trees. Of the single-line Sub lambdas, only invocation statements may be converted to expression trees.

First noteworthy detail is that Microsoft does not want to nail down the exact rules and that the specification is dated.  Why they didn't want to nail is fairly visible, the restrictions are quite crippling and they would have wanted to leave room for improvement.

It does otherwise state explicitly why neither compiler version can convert your multi-line lambda method, only single-line is supported.  Next part of the sentence explains why you can't make it work on VS2015, you are using an assignment statement and not a method invocation.

So this strongly hints that VS2013 was at fault, it should not have accepted your lambda method.  It is a given that the very drastic Roslyn parser rewrite would tighten-up the syntax rules and avoid replicating bugs in previous versions.  Also plenty of room to worry that the VS2013 code did not actually work correctly.  Non-zero odds that it incorrectly parsed the lambda as an expression instead of a statement.  In other words, getting a comparison expression instead of an assignment statement.  VB.NET does open the door to this kind of ambiguity, the `=` operator is used both in expressions and assignment statements.  This is a guess I cannot verify without a repro.

Best to bounce this off the guys that actually wrote the compiler.  You can file a feedback report at connect.microsoft.com.  Be sure to include a minimum repro that they can compile or they'll quickly give up.  Beware that there are good odds that they will close it as "By design".  That's what it looks like.

Comment: Thanks Hans, that's the direction I was leaning with this. I guess I'll create methods for tests like this.

Comment: Interestingly, if you use the 2015 Extract Method functionality you get `x = VerifyLoginFieldError(x)`, which goes along with what you were saying about ambiguity with the `=` operator.